# Removing some files from a broccoli tree

Tags: node.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am using ember-cli and broccoli.

A tree is generated containing all of the files from my application. This tree is passed to [broccoli-manifest](https://github.com/racido/broccoli-manifest) to generate a HTML5 application cache manifest file. However, I would like to exclude some of the files from being written to the manifest (they shouldn't be available offline - a FALLBACK is instead specified in the manifest).

My first thought was to submit a pull request to broccoli-manifest allowing you to pass an option containing a list of files to ignore (e.g. not output into the manifest).

Then it occurred to me that perhaps a more broccoli way to approach it would be to somehow filter the tree before passing it in to broccoli-manifest.

e.g. something like:

```
var completeTree = app.toTree();
var filteredTree = imaginaryFilteringFunction(completeTree, {
  exclude: ['assets/is-online.json']
});
module.exports = mergeTrees([completeTree, writeManifest(filteredTree, {
  fallback: ['assets/is-online.json assets/offline.json']
})]);
```

Does something like my `imaginaryFilteringFunction` exist in broccoli land? Should it? Or should I go about this in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on the [ember.js discussion forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/removing-some-files-from-a-brocolli-tree/6095) and rwjblue was kind enough to provide me with the answer which was to use [broccoli-file-remover](https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-file-remover).

e.g.

```
var removeFile = require('broccoli-file-remover');

var filteredTree = removeFile(completeTree, {
  paths: ['assets/is-online.json']
});
```

Comment: how do you use this inside Brocfile.js?

Comment: Just like in my example code above (taken from an ember-cli brocfile). The `imaginaryFilteringFunction` is what you get back from `require('broccoli-file-remover')`....

There is more examples in the broccoli-file-remover readme...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this is referring to `broccoli-file-remover` which is now deprecated in favour of [broccoli-funnel](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel).

The new solution would go something like this:

```js
const funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

const completeTree = app.toTree();
const filteredTree = funnel(completeTree, {
  exclude: ['assets/is-online.json']
});
```

The benefit of using `broccoli-funnel` now is that it supports globs so you can remove all `is-online.json` files from anywhere in your tree using something like this:

```js
const funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

const completeTree = app.toTree();
const filteredTree = funnel(completeTree, {
  exclude: ['**/is-online.json']
});
```